# Bootstrap Modal doesn't toggle when I modal('toggle') on escape keydown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a function that is supposed to toggle a bootstrap modal on and off by pressing the escape key. However, the `toggle` function only shows the modal. I have to manually click on the exit button to have it hide.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
  }
});
```

I know that in JQuery, the `toggle()` event shows and then hides an element. I expected the modal to disappear after I pressed escape.

HTML

```
<div class="modal bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4></li>
        <li class="list-right"><button id="new">New</button></li>
        <li><button id="close"><span>&times;</span></button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Clicking on the button hides this modal

```
$("#close").click(function() {
  $("#myModal").hide();
});
```

Comment: Side Note: Toggle hides an element if shown and shows it if hidden - not show *then* hide.

Comment: This is because the `modal` plugin has already defined behavior for escape. Why do you want to change that? It is counter-intuitive to mainstream user experience.

Comment: [This will work fine with other keys](http://jsfiddle.net/bm7htruL/1/). I would strongly suggest that you _not_ change the default behavior because this is aggravating to your end user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work as intended is because the Modal plugin has already defined functionality for the [escape keydown event](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L141).

You can override this functionality but it will be messy and your end user will not be expecting this behavior. I would suggest you use this on another key and explain that to your user.

Something like:

```js
//enable tooltip for your message about toggling the modal
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});

//toggle the modal on tilde
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 192) {
    $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="modal bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4></li>
        <li class="list-right"><button id="new">New</button></li>
        <li><button id="close"><span>&times;</span></button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>click to open</button>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign text-info' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Press the tilde key to toggle"></span>
```

**Note:** Notice if you press <kbd>`</kbd> and then <kbd>Esc</kbd>, it will hide the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

instead of

```
$("#myModal").modal('toggle');
```